# Android: Compressed bitmaps from int.storage not loading dynamically

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a small issue with bitmaps which I want to load into a view with a picture in every entry. The application looks like this:
[Application layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Zfp.jpg)

I actually have two problems - the first is that when i compress the file in code by 90%, the result file gives me even higher file size, f.e. file before compressing was 500kb, after its 6MB.

The second problem is that the images are saved to internal storage of the application (/com.example.my.application/files/) but are not shown in the list itself. What you see on the picture is working when i use the pictures directly from gallery using URI of the files, although because of their size, the RAM usage gets too high and after adding 5-6 of them the application crashes.

Here is the code for getting selected picture, compressing and saving:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        File mypath=new File(new File(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"")+"/"+data.getData().getLastPathSegment()+".jpg");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageURI = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_image_uri) ;
        tv.setText(imageURI);
    }
}
```

This is the adapter of a gridview:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SolventViewHolders holder, int position) {
    ...

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(context.getFilesDir()+"/files/"+itemList.get(position).getUrl());
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(image));
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageURI(uri);

}
```

So basically the idea is that after an image from gallery is selected, i want to compress it, save it into /data/com.example....../ under the name specified by .getLastPathSegment(), and then load the picture using the same path with the last path segment which is unique for every object in the view. I guess Im missing something small, but Im not that good at it, so I need your help. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The second parameter in the `Bitmap#compress()` method is not the compression factor, it's the quality setting. The lower the number, the greater the compression. Also, you probably want to use the `JPEG` format, since `PNG` is a lossless format, and the quality setting will be ignored. And, it doesn't look like your file paths match. Check the values when saved against the ones you're trying to load.

Comment: @MikeM.Thanks, it works now.

But now im getting this exception:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51916812 byte allocation with 16776960 free bytes and 25MB until OOM

Comment: @MikeM. I tried to recycle every bitmap after i use it, but it doesnt seem to help...

Comment: You might consult the developer pages [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), and specifically [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html).